# General debugging options (VS2017): "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and struct with enum

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to debug code with some struct

```
struct VirtualArrayTest
{
    private T[] Array;
    private TypeCurrentArray CurrentArray;
    private int StartPos;
    private int FinPos;
    
    public enum TypeCurrentArray
   {
    Main = 1,
    Temp
   }
    ....
}
```

And I couldn't see the current values of these variable (type `VirtualArrayTest`). I was getting the messages **"The runtime is unable to evaluate this expression"**. If in my struct, I have variable **CurrentArray (enum)**.

I can decided this problem only by set option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".
Did I decide this problem right?

I didn't understand how it correlating with [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2017) regarding this option ? What does means the "default debugging engine" and the "legacy version" ? And why the "default debugging engine" doesn't support the inspection of these type of variables?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. You can mark it as answer, which can be beneficial to other community members. It can be easier for them to search the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Information**
Problem "Not possibility to see the current values of the variable of type VirtualArrayTest" is connected with existence in struct the field CurrentArray (enum).
Can be decided, also by other way (not set the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"), by replace the current variant of creation and initialization the struct:

```
        VirtualArray ArrayInitial; 
        ArrayInitial.CurrentArray = TypeCurrentArray.Main;
        ArrayInitial.Array = arrInitial;
        ArrayInitial.IndxStart = 0;
        ArrayInitial.IndxLast = iNumElements - 1;
```

onto either:

```
 `VirtualArray ArrayInitial = new VirtualArray(arrInitial, TypeCurrentArray.Main);`
```

or by explicit getting the value of the field **ArrayInitial.CurrentArray** (after creation struct by first way), by example it will also work:

```
var t =  ArrayInitial.CurrentArray;
```

After the first time of explicit getting the value of this field, VS2017 Debuger will show correctly value of all variables of that type (also without set option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode").
I don't know, Its a Bug or Feature.